# Upload openstack image failed

Tags: ansible, openstack

I tried to upload an openstack image with ansible. The task failed with

```
Failed validating 'type' in schema['properties']['tags']:: 400 Bad Request: On instance['tags']:: u&quot;['testtag']&quot;: 'items': {'maxLength': 255, 'type': 'string'},: 'type': 'array'}: Provided object does not match schema 'image': u&quot;['testtag']&quot; is not of type 'array': {'description': u'List of strings related to the image',",
```

Here is my ansible task:

```yaml
- os_image:
    name: test_image
    auth: "{{os_auth}}"
    container_format: bare
    disk_format: raw
    tags: [testtag]
    state: present
    filename: /var/lib/test_image.raw
```

---

I have changed it to  **- testtag1**  with new indent line however the error message its showing the quote:

```
u&quot;['testtag1']&quot; is not of type 'array': Failed validating 'type' in schema['properties']['tags']:: 400 Bad Request: On instance['tags']:: 'items': {'maxLength': 255, 'type': 'string'},: 'type': 'array'}: u&quot;['testtag1']&quot;: {'description': u'List of strings related to the image',",
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure you pasted the task very exactly as it is in the playbook/role you are running ? From the error, it looks like you have written `tags: "[testtag]"` (with quotes around what should be a yaml shortcut syntax for a list) and that the module is getting a string instead of an array (e.g. list). One thing you can try (in case of a possible bug in the module...) is write your list in "pure" yaml format (i.e. remove brackets around your tag, indent on a new line and prepend with a dash+space (`- testtag`).

Comment: I have changed it to  - testtag1 with new indent line

however the error message its showing the quote like "u&quot;['testtag1']&quot"



u&quot;['testtag1']&quot; is not of type 'array': Failed validating 'type' in schema['properties']['tags']:: 400 Bad Request: On instance['tags']:: 'items': {'maxLength': 255, 'type': 'string'},: 'type': 'array'}: u&quot;['testtag1']&quot;: {'description': u'List of strings related to the image',",

Comment: Please don't describe this in a comment: edit your question.

Comment: I got same error. Everything about cloud auth is ok. but i cant create image via ansible.